# How do I convert a value from Random to a string?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, random

I'm new to c# and I would like to use a value that a random method would give me from an actual array list. But I can't seem to convert it or use a console.readline() on it. Here goes my code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] mots = new string[] { "pomme", "animal", "pont", "ensemble", "visuel", "acronyme", "cellule", "article", "syllable", "programme" };
            Random mot = new Random(mot.GetHashCode());
            mot = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(mots[mot.Next(9)]);

            string mot = "pomme";
            char[] charArray = mot.ToCharArray();
            Array.IndexOf(charArray);
}
```

How do I convert the output into a string in order to use it afterwards? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a string to `mot` which is an object of class `Random`?!? What are you trying to do with that `ReadLine` at all?

Comment: `Random` != `string`. It's first, that you should to know

Comment: You are using the `mot` (english = word) variable in a lot of places which, apart from not compiling, is also confusing things. Can you list out what sort of value you expect the user to input (if anything) and what the program should then do with that input? If you approach it in this way, it is easier for you and us to see where things are going wrong.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for so many mistakes, I'm trying to do a program which will randomly select a word (string for me) from an array. Then the user will have to try to guest that word by putting in some letters. That's why I needed to sort this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get and output to the console a random element from the `mots` array:

```
var mots = new [] { "pomme", "animal", "pont", "ensemble", "visuel", "acronyme", "cellule", "article", "syllable", "programme" }; 
var rand = new Random();
var index = rand.Next(0, mots.Length); // returns a random int between 0 and mots.Length - 1 (see below)
var mot = mots[index];
var motString = mot.ToString(); // get the string value
Console.WriteLine("Random element: {0}. String value: {1}.", mot, motString);
```

From the [Microsoft Random.Next documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx:)

> The Next(Int32, Int32) overload returns random integers that range from minValue to maxValue – 1. However, if maxValue equals minValue, the method returns minValue.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the index. Create a random value with max value of the array length - 1. Then return the string at this random index.

```
string[] mots = new string[] { "pomme", "animal", "pont", "ensemble", "visuel", "acronyme", "cellule", "article", "syllable", "programme" }; 
Random Rnd = new Random();

string RandomString()
{
  return mots[Rnd.Next(0, mots.Length - 1)];
}
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask.